# RDLC will be broken when publishing a web site with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc, publishing, publish

I've a large web application solution in Visual Studio. This solution contains some RDLC (client report files) in its folders. Whenever I publish it using Visual Studio, all *.rdlc files breaks. Indeed they convert to files with 1 KB size.

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you publish locally or to a Web server? If the latter, did you try locally?

Comment: I publish locally, then upload published files into web site.

Comment: Interesting. I do the same thing, but RDLC files remain intact.

Comment: I've done it so many time in both VS 2005 and VS 2008. But RDLC files convert to a place holder just like when you publish ASPX files.

Answer (score 2):

i had a problem after publishing web application to IIS 7.0, the problem was that the reports were not rendered, however, i did the following and it worked for me :

1- download ReportViewer2008-2005 Redistributable from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cc96c246-61e5-4d9e-bb5f-416d75a1b9ef&displaylang=en) and install it on hosting machine

2- go to IIS Manager --> choose the Web Application which contains the reports, and then choose Handler Mappings

3- when in Handler Mappings, Add a new Handler, Set its info as the following:

Request Path : Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd

Type: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms (different verisons might be found, so use the latest)

Name: Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd

i hope this helps.

Comment: ReportViewer is used when a "server report" does not work in clients just because they have not correct ActiveX for rendering it. But my problem is completely different! 

After publishing my web app., all *.rdlc ("client reports") break and converts to 1 KB files that won't work in the application. BTW when I overright this broken files with their unpublished copies, they will be working again.

I'm searching for some way that prevents breaking *.rdlc files while publishing.

Comment: Actually, my case was not using server reports, i used Local Reports(client reports), and that what was problem, and solved it using the steps above, give it a try